# Is it possible to move an Animal Crossing: New Leaf save onto a different game card?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I rent (and still have) Animal Crossing: New Leaf. Since I might buy it later, and I have gotten pretty far into the game, is there a way for me to keep the save so when I buy the game later I can use the same save?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in a couple of situations, but it doesn't sound like it is in your case.

The more normal way to move is to just move. [IGN has a guide on how to do that here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/How_to_Move_to_Another_Town), but to summarize, you have to have your first house payment made, have another 3DS nearby with either a physical or digital copy of New Leaf already in it, and you have to not be your town's mayor, i.e. not the first save on your game. It sounds like you don't have another copy yet though or another 3DS, and you're probably your town's mayor, so that probably won't help your case.

Another option is to download the "Save Data Transfer Tool" from the Nintendo eShop. This requires you to have a digital copy of the game before you can transfer it, but it should work even if you're mayor.

If you just want to back it up for some possible case in the future though, I think you're out of luck. Some things do have "Save-Data Backup" as an option to the left of "Manual", but Animal Crossing: New Leaf isn't one of those things.

Comment: The key point is that if he wants to continue with his current progress the only option is to buy a digital copy of the game?

Comment: @Gwen: Probably, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one of these: http://www.hkems.com/product/nintendo/0907.htm

I have one and have been using it for a while, mainly to back up my Pokémon saves in case I want to restart or lend the game to a friend (or EV train without the effort (; ), but it works with 3DS saves now as well, so you can back up your save with it to your computer and then transfer it onto the new cartridge when you get it.

Though the digital thing works just as well and is simpler, plus you don't have to buy an extra (albeit extremely useful) accessory.

Comment: Mhhh... Good idea, but the thing costs around 34 $ (amazon price). If you don't use it very often, I wouldn't invest in one and just buy new leaf. ASIDE: Jesus Christ, that website is HORRENDOUS.

Comment: That Save Adapter won't work with AC:NL... Neither it (NDS Adaptor Plus) nor that other one R4i Save Dongle) as apparantly New Leaf uses a new Save Structure these adapters can't backup. Even IF they *could* it would still not help as New Leafs creates an ID on your System/SD which prevents you from using old Saves and will delete it (which happens if you copy back an old SD save...).

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to buy the cartridge from the rental company, or to buy from another source and swap the cartridges on the return.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to buy yourself an Action Replay 3DS power saves. Yea it costs $40 but you can save your game to it on your computer & add in max bells with it to your town too: which is a bonus!