# Help with Animal Crossing save transfer

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I am currently borrowing *New Leaf* from my step sister and I have now bought a copy of *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* for myself.. I am NOT the mayor on her game card, when I transfer my save data from her town to my new town, would i automatically become mayor? Or will I need to start a whole new game in order to become mayor?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. And good news! It seems that we have an [answer that might help you](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/125733/12937). If you don't think that this answer solves your problem, be sure to tell us how your situation is different, so we can try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

A save transfer can only be done by a player who is not the mayor of the town. When you arrive in the new town, you will automatically become the mayor of that town.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/How_to_Move_to_Another_Town)