# Is it possible to transfer your town from a physical copy of the game to the digital copy?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So I have 2 copies of Animal Crossing New Leaf for the 3DS. I have a physical cart version and a digital version I downloaded from the eShop. I use them both on the one console. The time has come where I could really use the money from selling the physical version, but unfortunately, the cart contains my main town, and I can't sell the digital version.

Can I transfer my town from my physical cart to my digital version? Ideally I want to keep my main town, but sell one of the Animal Crossings

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to move an Animal Crossing: New Leaf save onto a different game card?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125732/is-it-possible-to-move-an-animal-crossing-new-leaf-save-onto-a-different-game-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the eshop and download the save data transfer tool app. you can use the app to move the save. The save on the cart will be deleted.

Here is the official page:http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_la/gi_index.jsp?menu=save_data_transfer&submenu=ctr-gi-app-save-data-tool-overview